# How to publish my plugin?

Tags: firefox, plugins, publish

I created a plugin using FireBreath. My plugin is not commercial, but specific to my company's needs. The plugin interacts with our company's website.

In Firefox, when a user visits our website and doesn't have the plugin installed, a yellow bar saying "Install Missing Plugins" comes up. Is there a way to publish our plugin in a way that when the user clicks install missing plugins, our plugin will install through Firefox?

Furthermore, we need this functionality on all other browsers (Chrome, Opera and Safari) except for IE. Is this possible with these other browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Only plugins registered with the Plugin Finder can be installed automatically, but you can set the `pluginspage` attribute to your plugin download page and the wizard will suggest visiting that page to install the plugin.